# Different versions of same app, for iphone/ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, version

I have an app in the itunes store now. The problem is it's not optimized for the iphone, I don't really want to submit a new app that is only available for the iphone, is it possible to have two separate binary files. One that you can only get on the iphone and another that you can only get on the ipad. From the same store listing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's App Store management, not programming.

Comment: If you can wait for the release of iOS 8 then this issue will go away with a small amount of work. Otherwise, convert your app to a `Universal App` and add a different Storyboard inside the app for the iPhone. There are Apple WWDC videos showing how to do this and other instructions on the web if you do an Internet Search.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  add a version of the app in the iTunes. There is no other way to solve this issue. You have to set the application type as Universal which will support both iPhone and iPad . Make you you have designed separate Storyboards or Xibs for iPhone and iPad according to  your screens. This is the way you can solve the issue.